# How to receive Map parameters in Resteasy?

Tags: resteasy

I would like to receive these HTTP parameters (POST) in my Resteasy service:

```
customFields[my_key]=some_value
customFields[my_key2]=some_value2
```

Something like this doesn't work:

```
@Form(prefix="customFields")
Map<String, String> customFields
```

... what happens here is that on the server the new Map is initialized, and the key for the Map entry is set (i.e. "my_key") but value is not set.

Does anyone know how to handle the case like mine, where I need to receive unknown number of fields (within a Map), but each of them properly structured (HTTP map/dictionary notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-821). The workaround is to use your own string wrapper as the map value type. For example:

```
public class StringWrapper implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @FormParam("value")
  public String value;
}
```

Redefine your map as:

```
@Form(prefix="customFields")
Map<String, StringWrapper> customFields;
```

And then pass the values to it as `customFields[my_key].value=some_value`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is OK but unfortunately doesn't really work perfectly well as the client now has to use a non-intuitive, and changed, syntax.